# ISNULL not replacing with NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, isnull

I have following code -

```
   SELECT
       BR_CSNO AS [PARTY_KEY],
       'W' AS [PHONE_TYPE_CD],
       ISNULL( LTRIM( RTRIM( FAC_TELNO ) ), '0' ) AS [PHONE_NUM],
       NULL AS [UPDATE_DT],
       GETDATE() [BATCH_DT]
   FROM
       BASE B
```

I get following result -

[image]

It is not replacing the `NULL`. Why? Is it because of wrong placement or the usage of `LTRIM(RTRIM())` ?

EDIT

Sorry for my limited knowledge of SQL. I want to trim `FAC_TELNO` and replace it with `NULL` if it is a `0`

Comment: There is a difference between `0` and `NULL`, you know that?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you want to replace, and under what circumstances? 1) If `LTRIM(RTRIM(FAC_TELNO))` is `NULL`, then so is `FAC_TELNO`, so the trims are useless where this check is concerned. 2) You are replacing `NULL` with `'0'`. Your table does not contain a `NULL` (or if it did, it did get replaced by `'0'` - which means, it's working as it should. However, it can't replace anything with `NULL`, because that's not what your code is saying.

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: @Amadan - Ok, thanks. Here is what I need to do - I want to trim the '0   ' and then replace it with NULL (because it is not a valid phone number.

Comment: @Dai there is no `TRIM` in SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what I wanted. Sorry for causing confusion!

```
SELECT
       BR_CSNO AS [PARTY_KEY],
       'W' AS [PHONE_TYPE_CD],
       NULLIF( LTRIM( RTRIM( FAC_TELNO ) ), '0' ) AS [PHONE_NUM],
       NULL AS [UPDATE_DT],
       GETDATE() [BATCH_DT]
   FROM
       BASE B
```

Comment: This looks like the most succinct solution

Answer (score 1):

SQL has two functions related to nulls.

1. IsNull, which takes two parameters, a potentially null value and, and a replacement value if the original value is null.  IsNull(null, 0) = 0
2. NullIf, which takes two parameters and COMPARES THEM. If the comparison returns true, then null is returned, if the comparision is false OR null, then th first value is returned.  NullIf(null, 0) is null, NullIf(0,0) is null, NullIf(1, null) = 1.

It looks like you want to use `NullIf(ltrim(rtrim(fac_telno)), 0) Phone_Num`.

Comment: Yes! you are right. I wanted to use NULLIF and I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

why using LTRIm and RTRIM use TRIM it will work for me

```
SELECT
       BR_CSNO AS [PARTY_KEY],
       'W' AS [PHONE_TYPE_CD],
       ISNULL( Trim( FAC_TELNO ), '0' ) AS [PHONE_NUM],
       '' AS [UPDATE_DT],
       GETDATE() [BATCH_DT]
   FROM
       BASE B
```